# trackpoint: cannot move mouse pointer a short distance

Tags: mouse, trackpoint

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, and at the same time started using xfce.
My laptop is an lenovo SL-500, but I use an external usb keyboard with more or less the same keyboard layout (lenovo sk-8845, picture at http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/cn-wanghaic/IBM_SK8845.jpg).

I used to be able to easily move the mouse a single pixel at a time using the trackpoint of either device. I still can with the trackpoint on the laptop, but not with the external keyboard. It seems to always move (jump) 5-10 pixels, regardless how little I touch it. This is driving me nuts, since I can't do any fine-grained motion (e.g. getting the pointer within the small area allowing me to resize a window, or above a scroll bar to let me drag it). I tried tweaking both acceleration and sensitivity in Settings->Mouse and Touchpad, but regardless of the settings, the pointer still seems to move this minimum distance.

Comment: Can you clarify this is correct: your external touchpad used to move with single-pixel resolution with a previous version of Ubuntu / Unity, but you upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 / XFCE, and now the external touchpad can not move with single-pixel resolution? Have you tried using Unity or just XFCE? Does your touchpad have configurable resolution - see [Using xinput to determine touchpad capabilities](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics).

Comment: Well, I don't use the _touchpad_, but rather the trackpoint (the red knob located between the B,G,H keys), but yes, I used to be able to move the pointer a single pixel at a time (both with Ubuntu 12.04/Gnome, and also previous versions of Ubuntu as long as I've used this external keyboard). I still can with the trackpoint built into the laptop, but no longer with the one on the external keyboard. I've never used Unity.

Comment: I think this might be a dupe of [TrackPoint hard to control after Debian update](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43430/trackpoint-hard-to-control-after-debian-update). Do any of the suggestions there help?

Comment: @bain: Yes, it seems to be the same problem, and the suggestions certainly do help, but don't quite give the USB trackpoint the same "feeling" as the laptop one. The patches mentioned at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=682413 don't seem to be merged upstream; if I have time, I'll try and compile a kernel with those applied and see if it helps. In any case, if you make your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [TrackPoint hard to control after Debian update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43430/trackpoint-hard-to-control-after-debian-update) and the linked [Debian bug #682413 "USB TrackPoint keyboards unusable since synaptics-usb was included"](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=682413). It appears a patch to the 3.2 kernel changed the behaviour of the Synaptics USB driver so that it now reports raw values instead of normalised values. The fix patches from Andrew Deason mentioned in that bug report have not been applied upstream (see [tip:drivers/input/mouse/synaptics_usb.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip.git/tree/drivers/input/mouse/synaptics_usb.c)). If these patches do fix the issue for you, then please chase the issue up  on the linux-input mailing list so that it gets fixed upstream. You could also [contact the author of Synaptics-usb](http://jan-steinhoff.de/linux/synaptics-usb.html).